# CMYK形式のTIFF画像をRGB形式として色空間の変換をICCプロファイル無しで行いたい

Tags: java

#### 前提・実現したいこと

新米プログラマーです。
Java(eclipse)で画像フォーマット変換プログラムを作っています。
JavaのimageIOクラスでは、CMYK形式の画像を通すと、エラーを吐き出すので、
CMYKをRGBに色空間の変換を行わなければなりません。

その際、どうにかICCプロファイルを使わずにJavaの標準のクラスを使って
色空間の変換を行いたいのですが、やり方が分かりません。どなたかご教授願います。

#### 試したこと

下記のAPIや、
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.html
下記の情報を参考にしてみたのですが、
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/spec/j2d-color.html
ColorSpaceの使い方がいまいち分かりません。

ColorSpaceクラスの`toCIEXYZ(float[] colorvalue)`メソッドを使いたいのですが、
引数のcolorvalueにどんな値を入れればいいのか分かりません。

ColorSpaceクラスを活用した色空間の変換方法の一連の流れを
教えていただけたら幸いです。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

JREはJava9です。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/119378